# Optaplanner - HardMediumSoftScoreHolder - How do I force the solver to minimize medium score first then soft score?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I'm starting to work with optaplanner in order to do a poc, and i'll figuring an issue.
I implemented hard constraints and it is ok. Do the same with a medium constraint in order to handle a nullable planning entity and it was ok.
But, i added a soft constraint, and i'm not happy with the best solution. Let me explain.

Without the soft constraint, I have a score of 0/-2/0 and it is the optimal solution according to dataset. When I'm implementing the soft constraint, I get 0/-8/-13. But for me, I would prefer to have 0/-2/-700.

How can I managed this kind of behavior? How to minimize first the medium, then take care about soft?

With real example :

- i would like to affect a service to a resource if and for a period.
- MediumConstraint : Count total of unassigned services to a resource
- SoftConstraint : compute delta between desirated period, and planning optimization period.

For me, I prefer assign every services (if possible) instead of optimizing the delta between preference date and the assignment.

Below, the rules

```
//###########################################################################
// Medium constraints
//###########################################################################      
    rule "unassigned score"
        when
            accumulate( ServiceRequestAssignment(resource == null);
                                $cnt: count(1))
        then
            scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, -toIntExact($cnt));
    end   

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "dateDeviance"
    when
        $request : ServiceRequestAssignment(fixDate != true, $dateDeviance: dateDeviance);
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -toIntExact($dateDeviance));
end
```

Then, the config :

```
<constructionHeuristic>
 <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>

       </constructionHeuristic>
    <localSearch>
        <unionMoveSelector>
            <changeMoveSelector/>
            <swapMoveSelector/>
        </unionMoveSelector>
        <acceptor>
            <lateAcceptanceSize>600</lateAcceptanceSize>
        </acceptor>
        <forager>
            <acceptedCountLimit>4</acceptedCountLimit>
        </forager>
    </localSearch>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**In a step, OptaPlanner will always prefer `0/-2/-700` over `0/-8/-13`, just like you want.**

The problem is, that due to the change in the score function, it goes down another path and it doesn't reach the same score at the same time. There could be 2 reasons

- The additional score constraint's reduced the "score calculation speed". Use optaplanner-benchmarker to pit them against each other and give it 10 times as much time to prove that *given enough time it reaches that score too*. Then figure out the bottleneck in your score constraints (score rules) and make it faster.
- It's more prone to get stuck in local optima. Add additional out-of-the-box moves or add custom moves that escape such local optima.

In any case - not adding those soft score rules is not the recommended approach. Although that could work (first solve it without the soft constraints, then solve it again with them in, starting from the previous solution), that would be a hack. The real, good, long-term solution is to just add them, see if you can make them more efficient, set up the benchmarker (it's just a few lines now) and figure out what kind of custom move could get you from `0/-8/-13` to `0/-7/-9999`.

Comment: Hello Geoffrey. Thank your for your detailed answer. In fact, I think I find the issue. My rule "dateDeviance" is wrong. I don't know how to write it, but it seems related to this definition. I would like my planner optimize the solution according the score of all "dateDeviance". But it seems you can only specify rules on a PlanningEntity, and not on a PlanningSolution. I would like to minimize the global date deviance, so the sum of all my ServiceRequestAssignment

Comment: For variance, standard deviation, etc: the docs section "fairness/load balancing" and Tennis example might help.

Answer (score 0):

---

I think you can make the rule get smaller medium score or get larger soft score. for example:

```
//###########################################################################
// Medium constraints
//###########################################################################      
    rule "unassigned score"
        when
            accumulate( ServiceRequestAssignment(resource == null);
                                $cnt: count(1))
        then
            scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, -toIntExact($cnt)*100);
    end   

// ############################################################################
// Soft constraints
// ############################################################################

rule "dateDeviance"
    when
        $request : ServiceRequestAssignment(fixDate != true, $dateDeviance: dateDeviance);
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -toIntExact($dateDeviance));
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but i does not work. I tried to put my 2 rules as soft constraints and add a weight on dateDeviance. But like I said in the comment for Goeffrey, it seems to be related to my description of my "dateDeviance" rule. I will try to find the best definition in order to fit my goal

Answer (score 0):

According to Geoffrey's comment, I've checked again my rules and detect the problem is the definition of the "dateDeviance" rule.
For the moment, I don't know how to write the rule in order to fit my goal. But it seems more related to a definition error than a bottleneck or stuck in local optima.

I would like to compute the global date deviance of entire solution and decrements the score with this value. I can compute this score from Java method, but drools is not using the @PlanningSolution (ServiceAssignmentSolution.class) but @PlanningEntity(ServiceRequestAssignment.class). So from a move, i am currently not able to compute this value.

I tried to use accumulate and sum :

```
rule "dateDeviance"
    when
        accumulate(ServiceRequestAssignment($dateDeviance : dateDeviance); $sum : sum($dateDeviance))
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$sum);
end
```

But, the score is exactly the same of my initial post 0/-8/-13.

I need to consider the best solution according to all the assignment.
Is possible to use the class annotated as @PlanningSolution in drools file? Or using maybe kcontext variable and retrieve this one in order to compute in Java-way?